# Running Karma test with browser flash plugin disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, karma-runner, chai, enzyme

I am attempting to test a part of a component that will not be displayed if the browser does not have Flash plugin. The component detects flash plugin with the help of [swfObject](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject) and the logic mentioned below.

`MyComponent.js`

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
     // props...
  };

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isMobile: true
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    const flashVersion = require('../../../client/utils/detectFlash')();
    if ((flashVersion && flashVersion.major !== 0)) {
      /* eslint-disable */
      this.setState({isMobile: false});
      /* eslint-enable */
    }
  }
  //...
  render() {
  //...
    return (
      //...
        { !this.state.isMobile && (
          <div className="xyz">
            <p>XYZ: this content only shows up when flash has been detected</p>
          </div>)
        }
    );
  }
}
```

`MyComponent-test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import chaiEnzyme from 'chai-enzyme';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {MyComponent} from '../../common/components';

chai.use(chaiEnzyme());

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {

  describe('mobile/flash disabled', () => {

    const mockStore = configureStore({});
    const store = mockStore({});

    it('Does not render xyz', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(
        <Provider store={store} key="provider">
          <MyComponent {...params}/>
        </Provider>
      );
      expect(wrapper.find('.xyz').to.have.length(0));
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is this.state.isMobile is set to false as karma launches chrome and flash plugin is detected. As you can imagine the test also cannot work if it requires manually disabling Chrome's flash plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Testing if swfObject works properly is not what your test is about.

The best way would be to invert the dependency moving the responsibility to check whenever the client is mobile outside of `MyComponent` and just passing it in as a prop. This is called the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

For the test you can then run a test with the prop set to true and an other with it set to false.

So you would have `<MyComponent isMobile={true} />` and call the swfObject in the calling code.

Comment: I agree and I would actually go as far as to say the check should happen at the root component and reflect on the state. However, for the purpose of this test I was hoping to avoid such a change.

Comment: You could do both. When given the isMobile prop use it otherwise use swfObject. Then the change is not that big.